# save each element of rdd in text file hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am using spark application. In each element of rdd contains good amount of data. I want to save each element of rdd into multiple hdfs files respectively. I tried `rdd.saveAsTextFile("foo.txt")`  But I will create a single file for whole `rdd`. `rdd` size is 10. I want 10 files in `hdfs`. How can I achieve this??

Comment: Could you please provide some more details about what you want to achieve? By the size of the RDD is 10, I guess you mean the number of elements in it - and not the number of partition, right? Why do you want one file per element? What is their usual size?

Comment: because each element of rdd is different type of data. I want to save each element as a separate file.

Comment: ok - in this case you may want to consider a column-based approach using a `DataFrame`. For instance, you could have a column `Type` and `Content` where `Type` qualifies the nature of your data. Then you could write your `DataFrame` to a file with a partioning based on the `Type` column: `dataFrame.write.partitionBy("Type").save("foo")`. This should create one directory per type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can create a custom output format like this

```
class RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
       override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = NullWritable.get()
       override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = key.asInstanceOf[String]
}
```

Then convert your RDD into a key/val one where the key is the file path, and you can use saveAsHadoopFile function insted of saveAsTextFile, like this:

```
myRDD.saveAsHadoopFile(OUTPUT_PATH, classOf[String], classOf[String],classOf[RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat])
```