# Send data from hdfs to specific machines

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, distributed-computing

I have a big file stored in HDFS where in the last column I have a machine address, I want to send each row to the ap address and store it in a text file (on the local file system not HDFS) How can I do it? I can't find a way to do it in spark or hadoop.

example of the input file:

```
attr1  attr2 ..attrN  192.168.40.5
attr1  attr2 ..attrN  192.168.40.19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do it using hadoop or spark, since you can't tell those frameworks where to send data, But I have found a way to get the result I want, and the steps look like this:

1. Convert the string RDD to key/val RDD where the key is the ip, then group it by key.
2. Save each Item on a separate file on HDFS (this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682540/save-each-element-of-rdd-in-text-file-hdfs/51187055#51187055) will help)
3. Create a python script that use [parallel ssh](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh) to execute`hadoop fs -copyToLocal` with the appropriate parameter for each machine